Understanding the behavior of modulo operation while using TikZ
For the figure in display below, I want the first and second vertical lines along with every (9th,10th), (17th,18th) and (25th,26th) lines, which infact are the evaluations of mod to 0 and 1, to appear dotted. All except the first pair (0th and 1st line) of evaluation are drawn correctly.
I do not know of alternative solution in TikZ without using nested conditionals to draw same object (a dotted line) for multiple value matches (either 0 or 1) and only draw other object (undotted line) otherwise. Is there any ?

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% \foreach [evaluate={\sixmult=int(Mod(\y,8));}] \y in {-10,-9,...,9,10} {
\foreach \y in {-14,-13,...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...,13,14} {
  \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\y-2,8))}
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
    \draw[thick,dotted] (\y,5) -- (\y,-5);
  \else\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
    \draw[thick,dotted] (\y,5) -- (\y,-5);
  \else
    \draw[thick] (\y,5) -- (\y,-5);
  \fi\fi
}
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


When the first argument to mod is negative, the function returns a negative remainder. Instead of subtracting 2, add 14.
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% \foreach [evaluate={\sixmult=int(Mod(\y,8));}] \y in {-10,-9,...,9,10} {
\foreach \y in {-14,-13,...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...,13,14} {
  \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\y+14,8))}
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
    \draw[thick,dotted] (\y,5) -- (\y,-5);
  \else\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
    \draw[thick,dotted] (\y,5) -- (\y,-5);
  \else
    \draw[thick] (\y,5) -- (\y,-5);
  \fi\fi
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


In a different way, using expl3 facilities. First I define \modp to yield the nonnegative remainder and also an \intCase function that avoids nesting conditionals.
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\modp}{mm}
 {% computes the nonnegative remainder of #1 modulo #2
  \ddrookie_int_mod:en { \int_mod:nn {#1}{#2} } {#2}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \ddrookie_int_mod:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} < {0}
   {% add #2 to the remainder
    \int_eval:n { #1+#2 }
   }
   {% return the remainder
    #1
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \ddrookie_int_mod:nn { e }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\intCase}{mmm}
 {% #1 = integer, #2 = cases, #3 = code for no match
  \int_case:nnF {#1}{#2}{#3}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \y in {-14,-13,...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...,13,14} {
  \intCase{\modp{\y-2}{8}}{
   {0}{\draw[thick,dotted] (\y,5) -- (\y,-5)}
   {1}{\draw[thick,dotted] (\y,5) -- (\y,-5)}
  }{\draw[thick] (\y,5) -- (\y,-5)};
}
  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Thank you very much for exposing my flaw with use of mod.

@dd_rookie I added a different version.

Pardon me for ignorance, but unlucky me trying to get involved with some backgrounds on expl3 have bumped into 404 error here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/expl3/info .

I'm totally not used to this programming style. Initial expression defines the modp operation but only later you evaluate its arguments! Could you tell me about the general syntax please ? What (for example) is \ddrookie_int_mod:en ? Is it a class name, a function name or something else ?

@dd_rookie I fixed the links

While the mod function indeed returns a negative result if one of the parameters are negative, the Mod function does not (which, by the way, you use in the commented line).
I've also added the styles Mod 0 and Mod 1 so you don't have to repeat your path twice.
Code
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Mod 0/.style=dotted, Mod 1/.style=dotted]
% \foreach [evaluate={\sixmult=int(Mod(\y,8));}] \y in {-10,-9,...,9,10} {
\foreach[
  evaluate={\sixmult=int(Mod(\y-2,8));}
] \y in {-14, ..., 14} {
  \draw[thick, Mod \sixmult/.try] (\y, 5) -- (\y, -5);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

